# Internet Explorer not incrementing number for non-sibling <li> elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I've got some html that looks like this:

```
<ol>
  <div>
    <li>one</li>
  </div>
  <div>
    <li>two</li>
  </div>
  <div>
    <li>three</li>
  </div>
</ol>
```

Which looks like this in Chrome/Firefox:

```
1. one
2. two
3. three
```

But looks like this in IE:

```
1. one
1. two
1. three
```

If I change the code so that the li element is the parent of the div element instead of the other way around (so that all the li elements are siblings) IE renders it correctly. Anyone know what causes this or if this is the intended working behavior of IE? Furthermore is one way technically more correct than the other?

```
<div><li></li></div> VS. <li><div></div></li>
```

Comment: i think the real question should be about why youre wrapping your li's in divs

Comment: Come on, people. Down voting because you don't like the HTML structure? The question is clear and well formatted. People ask question to know better.

Comment: @Kobi, you're right, in general HTML is considered programming here on SO, +1 for this poor question.

Comment: @Kobi  You are wrong.  He/she did not bother validate their code before asking the question.  The answer is self evident to the problem.  A pass through through a validator would have disclosed this with crystral clarity.

Comment: Good point. I wish so many people knew they can/should [validate their code](http://validator.w3.org/)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply, `<div>` directly inside `<ol>` is not valid, so the secons option is better.

The [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2) are clear here, `<ul>` and `<ol>` can only have `<li>` elements. It is best to write HTML that follows the standard - when you don't, browsers are more likely behave unexpectedly.

Comment: Also, @biagidp, there is no reason to use a `div` inside each `li` - which will also solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid.  First of all the number that appears is default presentation from the browser, but is not a functional convention of HTML.  Secondly, validate your code and the problem will be self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding a LI tag with anything is incorrect. UL and OL can only contain LI tags. LI tags can contain anything.

http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/lists.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple...There are some priorities to be given to tags. also, " or

" tags can not be act as container tags. so it should never keep the entire structure.

Comment: Hello. You can add inline code by surrounding it with a tick, this thing: `\``